# try/finally with SBT tasks

Tags: sbt

I have an existing task called `myTask`, whose implementation I don't control.

I want to redefine it in this way:

`myTask := {
  val x = prepare()
  try
    myTask.value
  finally
    cleanup(x)
}`

As you probably know, this code wouldn't work, as we don't control when `myTask.value` is executed.

`prepare` can be called with `Def.sequential()`, and `cleanup` with the `andFinally` construct.  The only problem is how `cleanup` can get the return value of `prepare()`.

`Def.sequential{ 
  Def.task{ 
     prepare()
  }, 
  myTask 
}.andFinally(cleanup(???))`

One workaround is to use global variables, but this is a dirty hack.

Any ideas?

[Related doc](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Combined+Pages.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to the following solution that doesn't require to use any kind of the global state.

```
val initializer = taskKey[Int]("an initializer that makes something and returns some data")
val tryFinallyTask = taskKey[Unit]("a task that requires initializing and finalizer based on init results")
val myTask = taskKey[Unit]("your main task that can fail")

myTask := {
  if(scala.util.Random.nextBoolean()) throw new Exception()
}

initializer := { scala.util.Random.nextInt() }

// the task you would like to execute in a try-finally fashion
myTask := {
  if(scala.util.Random.nextBoolean) throw new Exception()
}

initializer := {
  // some logic here
  scala.util.Random.nextInt()
}

def finalizer(initValue: Int): Unit = {
  println(s"init result is $initValue")
}

tryFinallyTask := Def.taskDyn {
  Def.sequential(
    initializer,
    myTask.andFinally {
      val initRes = initializer.value
      finalizer(initRes)
    }
  )
}.value
```

`tryFinallyTask` executes `initializer` and then `myTask`. In case if `initializer` succeeds, i.e. `myTask` starts execution, `finalizer` logic will be executed in any case.

Some notes to the code:

- `Def.taskDyn` expects a `Def.Initializer` of SBT task. This is the returning type of `Def.sequential` as well as `andFinally`.
- You have to get `initializer.value` inside of `Def.taskDyn` and pass it into the `finalizer` function. Accessing the value in `finalizer` will not work, since you can't use `.value` outside of SBT macros.
- You are free to use values of other tasks in `andFinally` clause, although the execution order of these tasks is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to use global variables, and it works ok, even though it isn't the most elegant way to implement it.

I have:

- project/MyTasks.scala
- build.sbt

snippet in `MyTasks.scala`:

```
object MyTasks {
   var x = Option.empty[String]

   def prepare(): String = ???
   def cleanup(x: String): Unit = ???
}
```

snippet in `build.sbt`:

```
myTask := Def.sequential{ 
  Def.task{ 
     MyTasks.x = Some(MyTasks.prepare())
  }, 
  myTask 
}.andFinally {
     MyTasks.cleanup(MyTasks.x.get)
     MyTasks.x = None
}.value
```

In this way, we can get the state from `prepare`, and bypass SBT limitations.